# Editable SWT table

Tags: swt

How to edit SWT table Values without Using Mouse Listeners?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the `TableEditor` snippets in the below link help?

[SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)

The first example in the `TableEditor` section uses a `SelectionListener` on the table (unlike the second example which uses a MouseDown event you mentioned you don't want)

You could perhaps make use of the `TraverseListener` or `KeyListener` too to help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 6):

```
    final int EDITABLECOLUMN = 1;
tblProvisionInfo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // Clean up any previous editor control
            final TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(tblProvisionInfo);               
            // The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
            // not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
            editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.minimumWidth = 50;
            Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
            if (oldEditor != null)
                oldEditor.dispose();                

            // Identify the selected row
            TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // The control that will be the editor must be a child of the
            // Table
            Text newEditor = new Text(tblProvisionInfo, SWT.NONE);
            newEditor.setText(item.getText(EDITABLECOLUMN));

            newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) {
                    Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                    editor.getItem()
                            .setText(EDITABLECOLUMN, text.getText());
                }
            });         
            newEditor.selectAll();
            newEditor.setFocus();           
            editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, EDITABLECOLUMN);      

        }
    });
```

Here `tblProvision` is the name of your table. you can just now edit Your table by clicking on it. I have Declare `EDITABLECOLUMN`. this is the `column`  that u want to edit.

Comment: In this case, only one column could be editable.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JFace as well and not *just* pain SWT, have a look at the [JFace Snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets), especially

- [Snippet036FocusBorderCellHighlighter](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet036FocusBorderCellHighlighter.java?view=markup) - Demonstrates keyboard navigation by highlighting the currently selected cell with a focus border showing once more the flexibility of the new cell navigation support
- [Snippet034CellEditorPerRowNewAPI](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet034CellEditorPerRowNewAPI.java?view=markup) - Demonstrates different CellEditor-Types in one COLUMN with 3.3-API of JFace-Viewers

Answer (score 0):

You can get or set the value of a item, for example:

```
Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.NONE);
TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("My new Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to us [TableViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html), it is very powerful table which it you can use databinding very easy too.